# Django mysql EnumField does not appear on HTML page

Tags: django-forms

I created a form using mysql EnumField but this field does not appear on the HTML page when it is created.

**forms.py** - see transaction_type_1 that does not appear on he HTML page.

```
from django import forms
from .models import tledger_account, tfirst_free_number
from django_mysql.models import EnumField
from datetime import datetime

class Transactions(forms.Form):
transaction_no = forms.IntegerField(initial=1)
description = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
transaction_date = forms.DateField()
sequence_1 = forms.IntegerField()
transaction_type_1 = EnumField(choices=['Debit','Credit'])
ledger_account_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=tledger_account.objects.filter(active='Yes'))
amount_1 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
sequence_2 = forms.IntegerField()
transaction_type_2 = EnumField(choices=['Debit', 'Credit'], default='Debit')
ledger_account_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=tledger_account.objects.filter(active='Yes'))
amount_2 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get 'initial' argument if any
    #initial_arguments = kwargs.get('initial', None)
    updated_initial = {}
    updated_initial['transaction_no'] = tfirst_free_number.objects.get(id=1).ffn
    updated_initial['transaction_date'] = datetime.today
    updated_initial['sequence_1'] = 1
    updated_initial['sequence_2'] = 2
    updated_initial['transaction_type_1'] = 'debit'
    kwargs.update(initial=updated_initial)
    super(Transactions, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a model thus the form does not really know how to display it. You should declare a valid form field type that would be then put in the database or use something like this:
https://pypi.org/project/django-enumfield/